# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_2^x \frac{t}{\log t}dt$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I'm having difficulty with the Asymptotic expansion of $∫_2^x \dfrac{t}{\log t}dt$

using integration by parts with $u = \dfrac{1}{\log {\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $dv=t$ and 
$du = \dfrac{1}{x\log ^2{\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $v=\dfrac{t^2}{2}⁡$ to obtain

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Li}(x^2)
&=\int_2^x\frac{t}{\log(t)} dt\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2\log(x)}+C_1+\int_2^x\frac{t}{2\log^2(t)}\\
\end{align}

then the next iteration with $u = \dfrac{1}{2\log ^2{\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $dv=t$ and 
$du = \dfrac{1}{x\log ^3{\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $v=\dfrac{t^2}{2}⁡$ to obtain

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Li}(x^2)
&=\frac{x^2}{2\log(x)}+\frac{x^2}{4\log^2(x)}+C_1+\int_2^x\frac{t}{2\log^3(t)}\\
\end{align}

another iteration with $u = \dfrac{1}{2\log ^3{\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $dv=t$ and 
$du = \dfrac{3}{2x\log ^4{\left(t\right)}}⁡$ and $v=\dfrac{t^2}{2}⁡$ to obtain

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Li}(x^2)
&=\frac{x^2}{2\log(x)}+\frac{x^2}{4\log^2(x)}+\frac{x^2}{4\log^3(x)}+C_1+\int_2^x\frac{3t}{4\log^4(t)}\\
\end{align}

and so forth. Only I have gone wrong somewhere, but where?

P.S Maxima and Wolfram Alpha will not do this in this form as far as I know. Not sure about sage. That leaves me looking for help.

Comment: What is  $\, n?$

Comment: good question typo will correct thanks

Comment: Who says you went wrong somewhere? You are off by a constant, since $$\int_2^x \frac{t}{\log t}\,dt = \int_2^x \frac{d(t^2)}{\log (t^2)} = \int_4^{x^2} \frac{dt}{\log t} = \operatorname{Li}(x^2) - \operatorname{Li}(4),$$ but for the asymptotic expansion, that is immaterial. One way is to use an asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{Li}$ and just plug in $x^2$. That yields $$\sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{(k-1)! x^2}{\bigl(\log (x^2)\bigr)^k} + O\bigl(x^2(\log x)^{-(m+1)}\bigr).$$ Fits what you have so far.